# Xcode 9.4 Playground Swift Console Outputting

Tags: swift, swift-playground

[image]I just decided to learn Swift as a new language and I downloaded Xcode and have been following the Apple's Swift learning course. The console won't print() anything. I know it can't be a syntax error, because I haven't even touched the code that they have as an example that is supposed to show the print() function working. I do have the bottom pane open and the pane on the right open as well.

Debugging Tried So Far:

I tried the "view -> Show Assistant Editor". No dice... I Originally had Xcode 9.4.1 and saw that it had just been released, so I uninstalled and downloaded Xcode 9.4 thinking that it might solve the issue.

Thanks for the help!

Screen shot: [image]

Comment: I would say that you should have the dubug editor at the bottom of the screen open but it sounds like you already have it open. Also try typing `print("str is \(str)")` below the line of code apple has provided

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, brother. Yeah, the debug editor panel is open. I tried  let str = "str"    print("str is \(str)") and it didn't work. Any other suggestions?

Comment: can you post a screenshot?

Comment: you can post the screenshot to the question directly and put a comment here once you have posted it so I know you posted it.

Comment: Nope. I've also noticed that whenever I open Xcode it runs hella slow. I added to the above ^^ comment I wrote. My kids were talking to me while I was typing and I realized I had never said it didn't work. My bad

Comment: Awesome. Yeah, I'll send a screen shot to on the thread. Do I do that by editing the original post and it gives me an option to post a jpg?

Comment: Yes, that is how you should post it

Comment: what happens when you try to press the play button a bunch of times at the bottom left?

Comment: I previously had it on play. I just tried hitting the play button like 12 times and it doesn't do anything. The "Running" text with the loading wheel is there and the wheel just keeps spinning.

Comment: A redit thread suggests to run the Playground under macOS rather than IOS if you are learning Swift and writing simple code. For some reason the IOS simulator wants to crash or hang but the macOS playground seems to work fine. I am running Xcode 9.4.1

Answer (score 1):

Your code is still compiling (translating to machine code) here (recognise this by looking at the toolbar at the top). You should wait a few moments until it's finished. Your code is correct.

If it takes longer, try restarting Xcode or even your Mac.

Code recompiles every time you make a change in an Playground. This isn't the case in projects. I wouldn't recommend using projects because

- they don't have instant feedback;
- contain other mess that will distract you from learning swift;
- they need to be rebuild every time you make a change.